# Javascript Prototype based class in default based class is that possible to use it?

Tags: javascript, oop

I would like know if it is possible to use (extends) a prototype based class in a normal class with the new ecmascript syntax ?

```js
function person(gender) {
  gender = this.gender;

}
person.prototype.identifyGender = function() {
  if (this.gender === "woman") {
    console.log("woman");
  } else {
    console.log("man");

  }
};
let persona = new person("woman");


class Animal extends person {

  constructor(gender) {
    super(gender);

  }
}
let animal1 = new Animal("woman");

console.log(animal1.identifyGender())
```

I get every time undefiend. Can anybody help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: What is `gender = this.gender;` supposed to do? Did you mean `this.gender = gender`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `person` constructor, you are setting the `gender` argument equal to the (as of yet non-existant) `this.gender`, when you really want the other way around, to set `this.gender = gender;`

Furthermore, `person.identifyGender()` doesn't return anything, it outputs to console.log. So calling `console.log(animal1.identifyGender())` will result in 'undefined', because `identifyGender()` doesn't return anything.

But yes you can extend your `person` class, the way you have it will work once the class is fixed.